# PAM модуль. Пользователь ввел неверный пароль

Tags: c++, linux, c, unix

Делаю, свой PAM модуль. Если пользователь не проходит аутентификацию, то мне нужно сделать что-то. Как мне узнать что пользователь не прошел аутентификацию?

---

1. Извините, что сразу не ответил.
2. Решил не изобретать велосипед и реализовать свой PAM модуль на основе другого PAM модуля. А именно pam_tally.
3. Не судите строго, лень было исправлять "некрасивости".
4. Все объяснения есть в репозитории, если есть вопросы, задавайте.

P.S. Ссылка на реп [тык](https://github.com/Darkcacok/pam_count)

Comment: unux != linux. Везде по разному можно узнать. У вас какая система?

Comment: Debian based  Astra

Comment: @misdeed, POSIX тем не менее никто не отменял.

Comment: https://habr.com/company/aktiv-company/blog/144700/

Comment: Это я уже  видел

Answer (score 1):

У меня нет под рукой машины с Debian'ом, так что пусть Вас не смущает ssh на скриншотах.

Ниже представлен простой скрипт, который выводит время и сообщение об ошибке аутентификации. Обратите внимание, что заканчивается он вызовом `exit` с нулем в качестве аргумента.

```
#!/bin/bash

dt=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

echo "[$dt] authentication failure" >> /var/log/auth_fails

exit 0
```

Это содержимое файла /etc/pam.d/common-auth до внесения изменений:

[image: imgdsc-confold]

После строки:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

добавляем новое правило и увеличиваем на единицу параметр `success` из предыдущего правила:

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [default=ignore]                pam_exec.so seteuid /var/auth-notifier.sh
```

[image: imgdsc-confnew]

Собственно, все, минимальный пример готов - попробуйте залогиниться с неправильным паролем, а затем проверьте содержимое файла `/var/log/auth_fails`.

Comment: Текст очень желательно приводить текстом, а не картинками.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, добавил исходный код скрипта, скриншот удалил.